# Deploy Shortcut With GPO with PowerShell ExecutionPolicy

Tags: powershell, shortcuts, group-policy

I am trying to deploy a shortcut to a selected couple desktops using GPO to the desktop. The target of the shortcut is

powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "C:\Scripts` Box\script.ps1"

It will not make the shortcut for the script on the desktop. I have no logs saying why. Can GPO not make these kinds of shortcuts?

Comment: The most obvious reason would be the space in the path to the file. If you run that exact string manually, what error dialog, is displayed if any?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't get an error. It runs the script as required.

Comment: How are you trying to create the shortcut? You just said the shortcut isn’t created.  If you say create a shortcut to something else does it work? I am familiar with Active Directory. Trying to understand the current situation

Comment: @Ramhound if I make a shortcut to the script specifically it makes the shortcut without a problem.

Comment: So if you create a shortcut, and link to that shortcut, the shortcut is created. But if you link to the script instead the shortcut isn’t created. I’ll be honest I have never not created a shortcut and linked to it when doing what you describe

Comment: @Ramhound so the shortcut I have in GPP points to the script. I should be making a shortcut to a shortcut?

Comment: I would use FILE from GPP, create the shortcut/lnk with all the parameters from a machine with the ability to create it pointing to valid location, and then use GPP to copy it over to the necessary area. This on uses computer level GPPs for public desktop but you can use this with user level GPPs too with conditional targeting to get user level and computer specific: https://i.imgur.com/OVOqqeN.png—but yes this is possible with GPO using GPP as this example.